# Why method findIndex() not working when using data from API?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, react-hooks, use-state

I'm having problems accessing data from API calls. I am trying to access object from the array that has the `nutrientName: "Energy"`

`9: {nutrientId: 1008, nutrientName: "Energy", nutrientNumber: "208", unitName:...`

In this case its `[9]`, but with each different food item the index is unknown and I am trying to use `Array.findIndex()` and get error `'foodNutrients' is not defined`.

```
const [meals, setMeals] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getData();
  }, [])

  async function getData() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get(`https://api.nal.usda.gov/fdc/v1/foods/search?api_key=${encodeURIComponent(params.api_key)}&query=${encodeURIComponent(params.query)}&`);
      setMeals(response.data.foods)
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  console.log(meals[0].foodNutrients[9].value) **Works**
  console.log(meals[0].foodNutrients[foodNutrients.findIndex(x => x.nutrientName == "Energy")].value) NOT WORKING
```

Comment: Where did you define `foodNutrients`? Is it from the API?

Comment: how are you attempting `foodNutrients.findIndex()` when `foodNutrients` is not defined w/in the scope of your function?

Comment: `meals[0].foodNutrients[foodNutrients.findIndex(...` should probably be `meals[0].foodNutrients[meals[0].foodNutrients.findIndex(...`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a multi-step version that clarifies what you're doing.

```
let nutrients = meals[0].foodNutrients;
let nutrientIndex = nutrients.findIndex(x => x.nutrientName == "Energy");
console.log(nutrients[nutrientIndex].value);
```

Combined, it looks like this:

```
let nutrientValue = meals[0].foodNutrients[meals[0].foodNutrients.findIndex(x => x.nutrientName == "Energy")].value;
console.log(nutrientValue);
```

***But even more simply, use `find()` instead of `findIndex()`:***

```
let nutrientValue = meals[0].foodNutrients.find(x => x.nutrientName == "Energy").value;
console.log(nutrientValue);
```

You're doing extra logic by using `findIndex()` whereas `find()` would be adequate to return the object you're interested in, which you can then just get the `value` of.

*Note: This answer trusts your assertion that your hard-coded `meals[0].foodNutrients[9].value` reference works, and that the issue is about your use of `findIndex()` rather than the sync/async nature of your attempt to read the data.*

Comment: Thanks for helping me Mark, I have tried the last method and it gave me "Cannot read property 'foodNutrients' of undefined.

Comment: look this code works perfectly, but I just can't access that index dynamically.
```
{Meals.map(meal => (
            <li>{meal.foodNutrients[9].value}</li>
        ))}
```
I have made a screenshot of the data structure, is there a mistake somewhere?

https://imgur.com/GiCxLnq

Comment: You need to place your data and code into a minimal reproducible example for inspection https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.  I suspect you are trying to apply array logic (find/findIndex) on objects. But until you do the work of placing it into an almost-working example, I can't help you further.